# using template parameters in java interface declaration

Tags: java, templates, interface, prototype-pattern

I come from C++ and I'm taking a Java class right now, studying design patterns more specifically. Last class, the professor gave us an example project to help us get started with the Prototype pattern and there was an interface declaration in the project which I didn't understand very well (and didn't ask the professor either :/)

```
package pattern.prototype.impl;

public interface IPrototype<T extends IPrototype> extends Cloneable {

    //clone: Permite realizar una clonacion superficial del prototipo.
    public T clone();

    //deepClone: Permite realizar una clonación profunda del prototipo.
    public T deepClone();
}
```

could anyone give me some kind of explanation regarding the use of parameter `T` in this context `IPrototype<T extends IPrototype>`. What is its purpose there? Is it necessary or just one way of doing it?

Thank you

Comment: This called the "Curiously re-occurring template pattern".

Comment: Java does **not** have C++ template parameters. That is a Java generic type. It is being named `T`, and declared that `T` must implement `IPrototype`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Comment: Was also going to say that Java generic types are not at all the same as C++ templates.  Important to keep the two distinct in one's mind, in spite of the similar syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the "Curiously re-occurring template pattern". As the name suggests, it was discovered for code written in C++ which uses templates, however, the pattern works with Generics in Java as well.

Here I can implement the interface as follows:

```
public class ConcretePrototype implements IPrototype<ConcretePrototype > {
    @Override
    public ConcretePrototype clone() { ... }

    @Override
    public ConcretePrototype deepClone() { ... }
}
```

Notice the method signature of the overriden methods. The base interface `IPrototype` does not know about `ConcretePrototype`, however, by using CRTP we can enforce that `ConcretePrototype` returns values of its own type.

Comment: from your answer, can you tell me if these two assumptions are correct, please? 1) `<T extends IPrototype>`'s only purpose is to allow us to declare `public T clone();` using `T`. 2) if all the interface's methods were, for instance, `void`, we would not need `<T extends IPrototype>`.

Comment: @Scaramouche 1) For the code provided yes. It could also be used for parameters in the method signatures. 2) If you don't use the type then you don't need a type parameter. A slightly different way of writing the methods could be, `IPrototype clone();`, but then you would have to potentially cast the result to `ConcretePrototype`, which may or may not cause you extra work. eg if you have a variable `ConcretePrototype p = new ConcretePrototype();` then do you want to write `ConcretePrototype pClone = p.clone();` or `ConcretePrototype pClone = (ConcretePrototype) p.clone();`

Comment: great, you answered those two questions AND the third question I was about to ask, thank you, finally, do you really think `IPrototype<T extends IPrototype>` should be changed to IPrototype<T extends IPrototype<T>> as markspace suggests?

Comment: @Scaramouche no problem! And yes `IPrototype<T extends IPrototype<T>>` is a better way to write the class definition!

Comment: @Scaramouche Without the type parameter you could write `class ConcretePrototype implements IPrototype<IPrototype>` which is probably not what you want the authors of the child classes to do. This would lead to writing code that looks like the non-generic example `ConcretePrototype pClone = (ConcretePrototype) p.clone()`. It depends on how strict you want to be. And generally you want to complete the type parameters or at least define them as unbounded directly : `interface IPrototype<T extends IPrototype<?>>`

Answer (score 1):

It’s not a template parameter, but a Java generic type, and it stands for any class implementing the given interface. In the context of prototype pattern it’s not necessary, just one possible implementation.

Answer (score 1):

T is type parameter also a generic type.

**T extends IPrototype :** To declare a bounded type parameter,T can be any type that is subclass of IPrototype

**public T clone();** return type would be generic.

**public T deepClone();** return type would be generic(means can be any type)

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I'm pretty sure the syntax you are using is wrong, so it might be best to inform your instructor anyway.

The problem is that `IPrototype` is used as a raw type here.  The second time it's used on the line, it's just `IPrototype` with no type variable.  That's a no-no in Java.

As for what is going on, all it means is that the type parameter for `IPrototype` must be a type of `IPrototype`--that is, some subclass of `IProtoType`.  Take a look at Java's `Enum` type, which uses exactly the same pattern: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html

```
public interface IPrototype<T extends IPrototype<T>> extends Cloneable {
//                                              ^^^ add this

    //clone: Permite realizar una clonacion superficial del prototipo.
    public T clone();

    //deepClone: Permite realizar una clonación profunda del prototipo.
    public T deepClone();
}
```